# Can you specify date-based partition keys when joining to related entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two related entities being mapped by JPA annotations backed by hibernate.  The entities both have sequence-backed identity columns in oracle.  Our also have monthly partitions, represented by a column called ENTRY_DATE.

```
T_MASTER     T_JOINED
---------    ----------- 
MASTER_ID    JOINED_ID 
ENTRY_DATE   ENTRY_DATE
             MASTER_ID(FK)
...          ....
```

To gain the benefit of the partition key, I'd like Hibernate to join on both the identity IDs and the partition key, but when I use the following annotation in the Joined class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns(value={
   @JoinColumn(name="MASTER_ID"),
   @JoinColumn(name="ENTRY_DATE")})
private Master master;
```

I get errors about having too many join columns.  I am forced to use

```
 @JoinColumn(name="MASTER_ID")
 private Master master;
```

I'm a bit of a JPA/Hibernate noob.  *Is it possible to use a partition key in addition to the primary key when joining to related entities*?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: Alex's method works, but I had trouble with generated sequences in test-mode.  The final code looked like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to declare both columns as parts of composite primary key in `Master`. Hibernate would not care that much about what is real PK in the database. Mapping wil be slightly more complex with @Embeddable but it should solve the problem.

Comment: Sweet! I tried using multiple @Id annotations in the master class, but breaking those two properties out into a separate, embedded class worked. Thanks Alex!

Answer (score 0):

yes.

Using native sql it looks as follows:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery( "SELECT {T_master.*}, {T_joined.*} FROM schema.t_master AS T_master OUTER LEFT JOIN schema.T_joined AS T_joined ON T_master.ENTRY_DATE = T_joined.ENTRY_DATE AND T_master.MASTER_ID = T_joined.JOINED ID " /*WHERE ... */ );
query.setEntity( "T_master", T_master.class);
query.setJoin( "T_joined", "T_master.joinedSet"); //joinedSet is the one-to-many mapping
query.setJoin( "T_master", "T_joined.master" );
```

Thus, you get to be very verbose on your query, and hibernate only acts as an object mapper.

Using Criteria or HQL, it is impossible to have OUTER LEFT JOIN ON some field other than primary keys.  This is why if you have such an option, use native SQL code.